# Issue in phpmyadmin

Tags: xampp

I have some issues on my phpmyadmin. If I search for any id it will showing the value in its view :

[image]

But when I select inline edit option they are not showing. Also if I fetch it through query I am not getting the values.

[image]

If I sort the result by clicking on column title its not working on first click. I have to click many times for this. This error suddenly occured today.

Should I change the xampp or this is due to cache problem or like that????

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a weird problem too. Try to restore default configuration, but start with the cache. If not, re install xampp.

Good luck.

Comment: Can it be due to very large database?

Comment: how large is your database?

Comment: I downloaded it and it was 70 MB database.

Comment: in this case, i don't think that it is a size problem!

Comment: What can be the problem? I got the data using mysql query in php file. But not in localhost/phpmyadmin view.